# How to accurately change the size of my object to a specific size

Tags: measurement

I created an object and want to scale it to 35cm. Now I am confronted with two problems: I don't know exactly where to set the workspace to metric system and when I tried to add a plane as a reference and changed the size, (I ticked measurement>edge length) it said that the size is 2mx2m no matter how I scaled it. I am getting a little frustrated here as I know this is probably pretty basic.

Thank you very much for your help!

Best,
Marlene[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can choose the unit system in the *Scene* panel:

[image]

To change the size, switch to *Object* mode and either change the size or the scale. At the end don't forget to apply the scale of your object to bring it back to 1:1:1:

[image]

Comment: I think I now know what the issue was. I additionally tried to find the size and measurements in edit mode and when I switched to object mode I could finally see the accurate sizes. Thank you very much @moonboots

Comment: yes it probably will be easier in Object mode

Comment: @die.marls if this answer has worked for you, consider clicking the tick next to it, to show it's cleared up.